# Putting values in array to create a JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string typeOfPerson { get; set; }
    public string personIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Persondetails personDetails { get; set; }
    public Name[] names { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string middleNames { get; set; }
    public string surName { get; set; }
    public string nameSuffix { get; set; }
}

public class Persondetails
{
    public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string yearOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string noOfDependents { get; set; }
    public string occupancyStatus { get; set; }
    public string mothersMaidenName { get; set; }
    public string spouseName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a following JSON with that:

```
"contacts": [{
            "id": "APPLICANT_CONTACT_ID_1",
            "person": {
                "typeOfPerson": "",
                "personIdentifier": "",
                "personDetails": {
                    "dateOfBirth": "1990-12-09",
                    "yearOfBirth": "",
                    "age": "",
                    "gender": "",
                    "noOfDependents": "",
                    "occupancyStatus": "",
                    "mothersMaidenName": "",
                    "spouseName": ""
                },
                "names": [{
                    "id": "",
                    "firstName": "Test1",
                    "middleNames": "D",
                    "surName": "Test2",
                    "nameSuffix": ""
                }]
            }


        }]
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything? , just use json serialize.

Comment: How do i put the values inside the array

Comment: `JsonMapper.ToJson<Person[]>( yourdata )` something like this

Comment: I am reading the values from the ASP.net form and then I want to put the values in these classes and build the JSON like I mentioned above

Comment: Are you trying to create the json using the classes you wrote and trying to figure out how to do that?

Comment: I am trying to create the JSON using the classes that I wrote and then put the values from my asp.net form to properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered building your classes like this ??
(The JsonProperty is the value in the JSON)

```
    public partial class Example
    {
        [JsonProperty("contacts")]
        public Contact[] Contacts { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Contact
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("person")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Person
    {
        [JsonProperty("typeOfPerson")]
        public string TypeOfPerson { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("personIdentifier")]
        public string PersonIdentifier { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("personDetails")]
        public PersonDetails PersonDetails { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("names")]
        public Name[] Names { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Name
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("middleNames")]
        public string MiddleNames { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("surName")]
        public string SurName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nameSuffix")]
        public string NameSuffix { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PersonDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("dateOfBirth")]
        public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("yearOfBirth")]
        public string YearOfBirth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("age")]
        public string Age { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("noOfDependents")]
        public string NoOfDependents { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("occupancyStatus")]
        public string OccupancyStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mothersMaidenName")]
        public string MothersMaidenName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("spouseName")]
        public string SpouseName { get; set; }
    }
```

and then you will serialize the object you create using:

```
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourObject);
```

and you will receive the JSON you want

easy class generation with this tool 
https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp

[Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this way. I am reading the value firstName, LastName etc from a form and I need to put the values to these properties from that form. The issue is how do I put the values in these nested arrays.

Comment: @Anjali Just use it as an object, create and access contact.person.names[i].firstName = "Inga" then serialize the object, and Boom you have JSON with these values.